# Failed post Image & data Using Requests DRF

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I want to submit text values alongside an image to an API. Another API using django-rest-framework.

I did this,

```
from PIL import Image       
from io import BytesIO
os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = '127.0.0.1'
response = requests.get(url_logo)
site_logo = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
files = {'site_logo':site_logo}
profile_payload = {"name":"Mark Johnson", "address":"dave str.blvd"}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
requests.post(profile_url, data=profile_payload, files=files, headers=headers, 
timeout=conn_timeout, stream=True)
```

I got this error.

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'PngImageFile'
```

Serializer:

```
class AddProfile(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=150)
    address = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=100)
    site_logo = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
```

I changed the site_logo to this:

```
site_logo = BytesIO(response.content)
```

Then it broke down totally by timing out and given me connection peer reset error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can I see your view and serializer classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's all in the error,

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'PngImageFile'
```

You're supposed to send a `bytes-like object` and not a `PngImageFile`.`response.content` is already a `bytes-like object`. So, all you have to do is:

```
import requests
os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = '127.0.0.1'
response = requests.get(url_logo)
site_logo = response.content #<<----Made a change here
files = [('site_logo',('<logo-name>',site_logo))] #<<-----made a change here too
profile_payload = {"name":"Mark Johnson", "address":"dave str.blvd"}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
requests.post(profile_url, data=profile_payload, files=files, headers=headers, 
timeout=conn_timeout, stream=True)
```

Do let me know if this works out for you.

Comment: After making the changes, no error from the image, but the serializer couldn't find the required fields like name and address.  Because I got an error message from the api I'm posting the data to saying "name is required" despite the fact I passed those data. Any idea of the issue?

Comment: And when I remove the content-type from the header, I got this error -  "File extension '' is not allowed.",

Comment: @YoYo I am not familiar with a serializer. Can you share some resource so that I can understand what actually they are?  Meanwhile, to check, you can try posting your data to `https://httpbin.org/post` which just returns whatever you posted.

Comment: This answer set me on the right path. I just made changes to the files. files = [('site_logo',('name of logoo', site_logo))]

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: @YoYo Ooops. Sorry for the wrong file format. I'm glad it helped!